# How to create a tree view in Android?

Tags: android

There are no controls in Android that provide Tree-like View. There is an ExpandableList View which I suspect could be used to creating one.

Have you tried imlpementing such a control?
How would one implement such a control in Android?

Comment: Can you describe your use case for a tree view? Oftentimes your desired scenario can be achieved in a mobile-friendly way using existing built-in views.

Comment: The requirement is to display a hierarchy of some sort, say for instance, a folder hierarchy. A parent folder can have one or more sub folders which can in turn have some more(Like the Project Explorer of Eclipse)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our company just open-sourced a small widget that is doing just that... You can see all the sources and add the project (as a library) to your own android project:

http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: Thanks for this piece of info!

Comment: I have a question about the tree view code. Where can i email you regarding that??

Answer (score 2):

take a look at ExpandableListView. Besides, see following thread:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg03587.html

Answer (score 0):

this solutions are, very complicate. but can use a ExpandableListView of more levels.

Example: [How to implement multilevel ExpandableListview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537674/how-to-implement-multilevel-expandablelistview-in-android/11057642#11057642)