# How to implement multilevel ExpandableListview in Android?

Tags: android, listview

Iam New to Android.My Requirement is to implement ExpandableListview with two Levals.

Means

```
   * Parent
     * Child
         * Subchild1
         * Subchild2
```

Like Above. Can any one Help me.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: See is the link for My project where N-level Tree list view can be achieved.https://github.com/Jaldips/Android-MultilevelTreeListView

Answer (score 4):

The ExpandableListView component doesn't support more than two levels, but in this [page](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html) you can find good solutions.